# Maintain responsive aspect ratio using only css

Tags: css

I'm having a bit of a hard time working with aspect ratios.

I am designing a tablet portion for my webpage.

On the main page I have an image slideshow.

The slideshow is responsive and changes size according to the tablet being in horizontal or vertical view.

I would like for the slideshows containing div to maintain an aspect ratio but also be responsive.

The aspect ratio I am trying to use is the size of a Facebook cover photo.

The dimensions of the photos are `851px` wide and `315px` tall.

I was doing some searching on SO and found:

`width: 100vw; 
 height: 56.25vw; /* height:width ratio = 9/16 = .5625  */`

I am having a hard time coming up with the math to keep the aspect ratio of a photo of those dimensions the same but responsive.

Biggest thing I cannot figure out is if my width is `width: 100vw;` then what would my height be to keep the proportions?

EDIT: Not a duplicate, my question is pertaining specifically to how to do the math to find the aspect ratio of specific dimensions using a specific method which IS NOT listed in the "duplicate questions" answers.

Comment: use `38.65vw` for the height. `100/815 = 0.1226`  and `0.1226*315 = 38.65` example : http://jsfiddle.net/m1eL6e8m/

Comment: I see. It was the math that I could not figure out. Thanks.